# Make a matrix with vectors

Tags: c++

I have 2 vectors of the same size and want to make a matrix with 2 columns and N amount of rows (N being the size of the vectors). How would I go about doing that

Comment: What did you try? Here, we do not help you to do your homework

Comment: What type are you trying to create?  If you have "2 vectors of the same size", you arguably already have a matrix.  Unless you want the data organized in some different way.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following :

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> vec1; 
std::vector<double> vec2;

// ... some code where you populated the vectors
// so that vec1.size == vec2.size == N
```

You can create a vector of vectors :

```
std::vector<std::vector> matrix;
matrix.push_back(vec1);
matrix.push_back(vec2);
```

You can then access the matrix:

`matrix[0][3]` will give you the fourth element of `vec1`